# Spark - Java - foreachPartition

Tags: java, apache-spark

My environment is as follows
Spark 1.6.1
Hadoop 2.6.2

Our requirement is as follows (all in **Java** Spark)
    1. Read a CSV file and apply a schema and convert this into a Data Frame
    2. Through a Spark partitioned SQL get all distinct partitioned data and iterate through in parallel

When i try the second step i am getting errors.

```
    DataFrame  sourceRowDF = hiveContext.createDataFrame(srcRowsRDD,source_Schema);
    sourceRowDF.registerTempTable("sourcetable");
    DataFrame  partitionedData = hiveContext.sql("select * from sourcetable distribute by region");

    partitionedData.foreachPartition( new ForeachPartitionFunc() {
    @Override
    public void call(Iterator<Row> it) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

the abstract function is as follows

```
public abstract class ForeachPartitionFunc extends AbstractFunction1<Iterator<Row>, BoxedUnit> implements Serializable {
        @Override
    public BoxedUnit apply(Iterator<Row> it) {
        call(it);
        return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
    }
    public abstract void call( Iterator<Row> it);
}
```

when i try and compile this code it gives me the following error

```
Error:(254, 39) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

what am i doing wrong please.

Thanks

Bala

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had to have a public static class in the abstract implementation. I changed the core abstract implementation as follows

```
public  static class ForeachPartitionFunc extends AbstractFunction1<Iterator<Row>, BoxedUnit> implements Serializable {
        @Override
    public BoxedUnit apply(Iterator<Row> it) {
        call(it);
        return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
    }

    public void call(Iterator<Row> r) {
      System.out.println("this is to test");
    }
}
```